# When i open localhost:3000 in Next Js, it automatically goes to 'http://localhost:3000/public/index' and shows 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I also don't have any public folder inside pages folder. I have index.js file directly inside pages folder. Still when i start server `localhost:3000/`, it automatically goes to `http://localhost:3000/public/index` and shows 404 error. Here is my  folder structure.

[image: This is my folder structure]

And here is my next.config.js file:

```
const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: false,
      webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.(mp4|webm|mov)$/, // Add any other video file extensions you want to support
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
             options: {
              publicPath: "/_next/static/videos/",
              outputPath: "static/videos/",
              name: "[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
         });

        return config;
      },
      output: 'export',
      images: {
        unoptimized: true,
      },
    };

    module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I have tried going back to my last commit. Still issue persists even though when i made my last commit, issue wasn't there.

Comment: Can you post your index.js file code?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this mistake, is that you need to delete the cache of Google or whatever browser you use.

You can find it in the local history in the right corner of your display.